# Entity framework is generating SQL that returns the entire table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

When I try to join a few tables the entity framework seems to be returning the entire table. As this table is quite large I need it to only return the rows needed.

I have three tables:

```
Project       - ProjectID, ProjectName
ProjectEmail  - ProjectEmailID, ProjectID, EmailID, RemovedFlag, CreatedBy
Email         - EmailID, Subject, Body
```

I am trying to retrieve Email data for a particular Project. 
When I do this:

```
using (DatabaseEntities context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    Project proj = context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID == ProjectID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (proj != null)
    {
        List<Email> projectEmails = (from pe in proj.ProjectEmails
                                     join e in context.Emails on pe.EmailID equals e.EmailID
                                     select e).ToList();
    }

}
```

The SQL that is generated is this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[ProjectID] AS [ProjectID], 
[Extent1].[ProjectName] AS [ProjectName],
    -- rest of columns appear here 
FROM [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ProjectID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=6
```

excellent, except that the second query generates this:

```
SELECT  [Extent1].[EmailID] AS [EmailID], 
    [Extent1].[Subject] AS [Subject],
            -- rest of columns appear here
FROM [dbo].[Email] AS [Extent1]
```

Email is a big table and I really don't want to be pulling back the entire table!
Is there a better way to return the list if Emails so that the table
joins on the correct keys?

I am also confused how it knows which Emails to return, because I can't see the first
or second query joining on the ProjectEmail table.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect between the table definitions you have provided, the EF query you wrote, and the SQL you say it generated. You say the Email table includes EmailID, Subject, Body, and the query returns the entire table, yet the SQL is over EmailID and an unmentioned HtmlFlag. Mind clarifying?

Comment: Sorry Anthony, I've shortened it all for readability purposes, there's a lot more columns there, I've just removed the unneccesary ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the where condition in the query.

```
List<Email> projectEmails = (from pe in proj.ProjectEmails
                             join e in context.Emails on pe.EmailID equals e.EmailID
                             where pe.ProjectID == proj.ProjectID
                             select e).ToList();
```

**Edit**

You are using `from pe in proj.ProjectEmails` where `proj.ProjectEmails` is of IEnumerable type. So this LINQ query becomes a LINQ-to-objects query. That is why it loads all the Emails in `context.Emails`. Try

```
List<Email> projectEmails = (from pe in context.ProjectEmails
                            join e in context.Emails on pe.EmailID equals e.EmailID
                            where pe.ProjectID == proj.ProjectID
                            select e).ToList();
```

Comment: Close but not quite. "proj" already contains only the ProjectEmails that I need, so joining that table onto the Email table works fine. The query is actually returning the correct data, so I'm stumped as to how it actually works.

Comment: That makes sense! I've added pe.ProjectID = proj.ProjectID... and it's now generating TWO queries, ha you've gotta laugh. The first one pulls back the entire Email table, and the second queries the ProjectEmail table! I'm new to this entity framework, I don't know anything about navigation properties. Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: @LachlanB, for navigation properties, you *should* be able to write something like `var proj = context.Projects.Include("ProjectEmails.Email").Where(yourPredicateHere).FirstOrDefault();` This should load your project with its project emails as a sequence, with each project email including also the email record, all in a single query. Try it and see.

Comment: And I deleted my original comment while verifying it, sorry if you needed it, but it appears Eranga got to the heart of it in his updated answer (and I've upvoted it).

Comment: @Eranga, that makes sense. The problem that I have now is that e.ProjectID doesn't exist, as it's a many to many relationship.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - I was hoping to avoid that syntax because I hate having magic strings ("ProjectEmails.Email") instead of code, where they can be caught at compile time (eg if I rename the Email table). But I'll investigate it anyway :)

Comment: @Lachlan, change it to `pe.ProjectID`. And I don't disagree with you about the magic string aspect, regarding the nagivation properties.

Comment: @LachlanB Fixed the typing mistake as pointed out by AnthonyPegram.

Comment: @Eranga, it works! A beautiful wonderful SQL query is my result :) Thanks heaps guys, very impressed :)